# Android - Populate menu upon activity onCreate

Tags: android, menu, contextmenu, oncreate

Perhaps I'm missing the obvious, but my menu is only been created and populated when onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) is called, as in [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu) example, and this only seem to be called after I press the menu button.

I would like to populate the menu upon the creation of the activity, how can achieve that?

UPDATE:

Perhaps a better question would be: 
How can I get the Menu instance of my Activity?

Thanks

Comment: Why? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to render the state(Enable/Checked/etc...) of the menu options upon events in the activity. prior to their first show call...

Comment: Why not just call the menuInflater for your menu?

Comment: put the method inside the onCreate of the activity?

Comment: Everyone seem to know something I don't... If I want to call the method as you have suggested, I require an instance of a Menu object, even a Dummy one... How do I create one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class which holds those states then set your enabled/checked etc from the properties of that class in onCreateOptionsMenu()

```
class MenuStates{

   public static boolean userDidPressTheButton;
   public static boolean serverDidRespond;
   public static boolean colorWasChanged;

}

void someEventHandler(){

   MenuStates.userDidPressTheButton = true;

}

void onCreateOptionsMenu(){

    myCheckBox.setChecked(MenuStates.userDidPressTheButton);

}
```

[EDIT]

You don't say why you want to get the menu instance.  One approach:

```
Menu optsMenu;

...

// this is called once only before the end of the Activity onCreate().
onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

    opstMenu = menu;
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

Following that, modify your menu as you wish.  Do any "as it pops" up work in onPrepareOptionsMenu().

The key understanding is the difference between onCreateOptionsMenu() and onPrepareOptionsMenu().

[MORE EDIT]

To completely control the thing yourself:

```
Menu optsMenu;


onCreate(){
    openOptionsMenu()    // the menu won't show in onCreate but onCreateOptionsMenu is shown
    closeOptionsMenu()

}

onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
     optsMenu = menu;
}

onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

   menu.clear();
   for (int i=0;ioptsMenu.size();i++){
       menu.add(optsMenu.get(i).getTitle());
   }

   return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

From the docs

> You can safely hold on to menu (and any items created from it), making modifications to it as desired, until the next time onCreateOptionsMenu() is called.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29

Comment: That is a solution I've considered, but I would still like to have access to the Activity Menu instance...

Comment: onCreateOptionsMenu(...) is only called for the first time I press the menu button... Am I missing something

Comment: Correct.  onPrepareOptionsMenu is called each time it's shown.  Read the docs! :)

Comment: I have read the document but OnCreateMenu is called the first time you press the menu button, and also onPrepareMenu... The next times only onPrepareMenu...

I want to create/capture/inject/get the instance of the menu beforehand dynamically.

Comment: How would you instantiate the 'optsMenu'

Comment: That's what inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, optsMenu); does.

Comment: The code snippet you've posted would never instantiate the optsMenu reference, and since inflate(...) returns void, my question remains... How would the optsMenu would be instantiated?

Comment: Edited again - with tenacity :)

Comment: To open the menu myself... That is an interesting approach. you think this would keep the menu hidden across all devices?

Comment: Not sure.  I don't <think> it can ever show since the laying out phase is not complete at that point and I have GS3, Tmobile Pulse, HTC Desire and a generic 10.1 tab running ICS all good.  However, I've done some more digging: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29 and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html, especially the difference pre-Honeycomb.

Comment: Nice Solution... I would use this one!

Comment: Unfortunately, calling these methods in the Activity onCreate() throws an Exception trying to add a window with token == null.